# Solving an initial value problem with addition: $\frac {dy}{dx}=(4+y)\cos x + 4x(4+y),\ y(0)=0$.

Tags: initial-value-problems

I am to solve the following initial value problem:
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=(4+y)\cos x + 4x(4+y),\ y(0)=0$$

I am aware that the general formula for an ODE/IVP is:
$$\frac {dy}{dx}+p(x)\cdot y=q(x),$$
and the integrating factor is:
$$I(x)=e^{\int p(x)\ dx}$$
However, do I expand the terms and solve like this:
$$\frac {dy}{dx}-\cos\ x\cdot y=4\cos x+4x(4+y)$$
so there are $p(x)$ and $y$ terms on the left and a $q(x)$ term on the right?

Integrating that is proving difficult and I think I have gone about arranging the equation wrong.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**
This allows me to have:
$$e^{\int -\cos(x)\ dx}$$
which is:
$$e^{-\sin(x)}$$

Comment: there's a mistake in your $p$ and $q$, in the $LHS$, you still have a factor of $y$

Comment: Is there not meant to be a factor of y in the LHS?

Comment: Exactly, but in your solution, there's still a factor of $y$, so I suggest you rearrange it again

Comment: No I mean, the equation for an initial value problem is:
$$\frac {dy}{dx}+p(x)\cdot y=q(x)$$
There is meant to be a y in there I thought.

Comment: it is $$y(x)=-4+e^{2x^2-sin(x)}C$$

Comment: May I ask how to get to that answer?
That is where I'm struggling.

Comment: You would write it as $$y' - (4 x + \cos x) y = 4 (4 x+ \cos x)$$ Easier is to use Separation of Variables.

Comment: Yes I have just seen my mistake, thank you for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=(4+y)\cos x + 4x(4+y)\\
\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=y(\cos x+4x)+4(\cos x+4x)\\
\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}-y(\cos x+4x)&=4(\cos x+4x)\hspace{25pt}\cdots\text{(i)}\\
\end{align}

Now (i) is in the form of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y\cdotp(x)=q(x)$.

So, Integrating Factor, $I.F.=e^{-\int(\cos x+4x)\:dx}=e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}$ .

Therefore, (i) can be written as:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[y\cdot e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}\right]&=4(\cos x+4x)\cdot e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}\\
\int d\left[y\cdot e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}\right]&=4\int(\cos x+4x)\cdot e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}\ dx+c\hspace{25pt} [c=\text{integration const.]}\\
y\cdot e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}&=-4e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}+c
\end{align}
Now, as $y(0)=0\implies c=4$.

Therefore solution is, $y\cdot e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}=4\left[1-e^{-(\sin x+2x^2)}\right]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!
It was after all the simple issue with me not factoring the y value correctly and using the integrating factor correctly also. I now see where I went wrong!

Comment: you welcome. my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve it as a [linear ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx), you would have to arrange it in the form you mentioned. However, note that your integrating factor is incorrect, because you did not put in in the form you mentioned:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x) \tag{1}$$
This is because you still have $y$ on the RHS. To do it correctly, do this instead:
$$\begin{align} \frac {dy}{dx}&=(4+y)\cos x + 4x(4+y) \\ &=4\cos{x}+y\cos{x}+16x+4xy \\ &=4\cos{x}+16x+y(\cos{x}+4x) \end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+(-4x-\cos{x})\cdot y=4\cos{x}+16x$$
It is now in the form of $(1)$. Hence, your integrating factor should be:
$$\mu(x)=e^{\int p(x)~dx}=e^{\int (-4x-\cos{x})~dx}=e^{-2x^2-\sin{x}}$$
Applying the reverse product rule and integrating both sides should now not be a problem.

---

However, note that an easier method to solve it is to realize that you can factor it as:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(y+4)(4x+\cos{x})$$
And then solve it as a [separable ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx):
$$\int \frac{1}{y+4}~dy=\int (4x+\cos{x})~dx$$

Comment: Thank you!
That also makes much more sense and I see where I went wrong, I was on the right track working away at this and I was close before I realised there was some solutions posted here!
Thank you!